# How to use strings in android

Tags: android, string, reference

I know this is a simple question, but I can't figure out how to reference strings in android. 
for example

on this EditText, I don't want to hardcode the string hi, I want it to reference a string in the res folder. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have following string in xml.

```
<string name="string_one">My string</string>
```

You have to access this in code :

```
String str = resources.getString(R.string.string_one);
```

You can also used in xml where you have take EditText :

```
android:text="@string/string_one"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file `strings.xml` in `res/values` folder, and add a text like

```
<string name="card">Card</string>
```

then reference the text in layout as android:text="@string/card"

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. All you need to do is create a string in the res value folder and then reference it

Comment: It took you 3 minutes to find a solution, maybe next time you should spend a bit more time in trying to figure something out by yourself instead of asking a question straight away. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Create a file strings.xml in res/values/ folder, and add a text  in it like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <string name="mystring">MyStringFromXML</string>
</resources>
```

then reference the text in layout as :

`android:text="@string/mystring"`

And in Java file do it like:

```
String string = getString(R.string.mystring);
```